# Access a JSON string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dna9H/1/) where I am trying to access json value, but it does not even produces any alert. What is the problem?

My JSON

```
{
 "response": [
{
  "id": "0",
  "elementName": "osname",
  "isEqual": true,
  "isPrasentinXml1": true,
  "isPrasentinXml2": true,
  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "osname",
      "firstValue": "Linux\u000a",
      "secondValue": "SunOs\u000a"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "elementName": "hostname",
  "isEqual": false,
  "isPrasentinXml1": true,
  "isPrasentinXml2": true,
  "attribute": [
    {
      "name": "hostname",
      "firstValue": "estilo\u000a",
      "secondValue": "buckeye.informatica.com\u000a"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I want to fetch `Linux\u000a` and `SunOs\u000a`, so i wrote

```
alert(compareData.response[0].attribute[0].firstValue+", "+compareData.response[0].attribute[0].secondValue);
```

Note: `compareData` Is where my data is in actual code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error was that you have quotes around your JSON and it was treated as a string. Also you forgot to replace `compareData` variable name with `jsonobj` in the second `alert`. Try the fiddle below, it seems it is what you want.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dna9H/6/

**EDIT:**

If your JSON is really represented by the string take a look at *Michael Sagalovich* solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Dna9H/8/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it in the fiddle, your object is the string. You need to parse it into an object first. `compareData = JSON.parse(compareData)` could help (`JSON.parse` is supported by the majority of browsers, I think). jQuery also has parser: `$.parseJSON(compareData)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax. This works:

```
var jsonobj = {
    "response": [
        {
        "id": "0",
        "elementName": "osname",
        "isEqual": true,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "attribute": [{
            "name": "osname",
            "firstValue": "Linux\u000a",
            "secondValue": "Linux\u000a"}]
        },
        {
        "id": "1",
        "elementName": "hostname",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "attribute": [{
            "name": "hostname",
            "firstValue": "estilo\u000a",
            "secondValue": "buckeye.informatica.com\u000a"}]
        }
    ]
 };

alert(jsonobj.response[0].elementName);
alert(jsonobj.response[0].attribute[0].firstValue + ", " + jsonobj.response[0].attribute[0].secondValue);
```

Please can I ask if you can install and learn how to use Firebug or Chrome's dev console. These tools can make your life a whole lot easier.